# Functions tutorial not clear enough

Tags: c#, function, methods

I'm absolute beginner in C# and object oriented languages in general so I find this tutorial on the web and stuck up at [functions](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/functions/#.UKJHhWe5e1s).
Now, it says:
you declare function like this:

```
public int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2) 
{
     int result = number1 + number2;
     return result; 
}
```

but it does not say that this method has to be outside of Main() method.
And also, it says the function is called like this:

```
int result = AddNumbers(10, 5);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

My guess is you HAVE TO put this code in Main() method, but it does not say you have to first make object so the correct code is:

```
Program add = new Program();
int result = add.AddNumbers(10, 5);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

'Program' is the name of the parent class.

So I'm confused now. I'm not familiar with C# versions, but as my conclusion this [tutorial](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/functions/#.UKJHhWe5e1s) is for C# 2.0.

Since this tutorial is on #2 for google "C# tutorial" my question for me and for the future learners is: 
is this mistake or is this the way you did it in C# 2.0 or is it just written in a such way so it's not clear enough for absolute beginners?

Comment: Try this one instead: http://mottishaked.com/training/dot-net-tutorial

Comment: There are also Console application tutorials on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288463(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is misleading. In c# there is no free standing functions. All executable code is placed in methods which belong to classes.

This is why it is best to avoid the term 'function' and use what is commonly used - method (of a class).

Methods can be static - those are called on the class and do not need a class instance, or instance methods - those require an existing instance which will have to be created first

Answer (score 1):

Their example isn't very clear for a beginner but it looks like they're assuming that you're calling the function from within the same class.

So something like this would work:

```
public class Foo
{
   public void Bar()
   {
     int result = Add(1, 3);
   }

   public int Add(int first, int second)
   {
     return first + second;
   }
}
```

This might then be used inside your `Main` method like:

```
public static Main()
{
  var foo = new Foo();
  foo.Bar();
}
```

As @Oded pointed out in his answer, the author has probably taken for granted the fact that you cannot nest functions.

Comment: `Main` is normally `static`, so the `Add` method would have to be `static` too, or the class instantiated for things to work, as far as this tutorial is concerned.

Comment: Making reference to `Main` is probably confusing in this case. I used it because the OP did. I'll change that to be avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Methods are related to instances, ao you should call them by creating an instance from the class and then call the method "same as you did"

However, `static` methods are class methods so you can call them without creating an  instance

```
 public static int AddNumbers(int number1, int number2) 
  {
 int result = number1 + number2;
 return result; 
  }
```

and you call the method by its class name `Program.AddNumbers(1,2)`

However, if the method is static you can call it within a static method within the same class without specifying class's name

```
 AddNumber(1,2)
```

Becuause `AddNumber` is a static method called within the same class `Program`

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial probably takes it for granted that methods cannot be nested.

A method cannot contain a method - methods should be inside classes or structures.

What you have done - the solution you have gotten to is correct, as far as the tutorial goes.